# Aurelia CLI and IE9

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm tying to make Aurelia-CLI support IE9.
As said [here](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/issues/236#issuecomment-220570291) we need "raf" to polyfill the lack of `requestAnimationFrame` in IE9.
They say to load it before the `aurelia-bootstrapper` as follow:

```
<script>
  System.import('raf')
  .then(function(raf){
    raf.polyfill();
    return System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
  });     
</script>
```

But with the `Aurelia-CLI` I don't have such script in the `index.html`, instead there is:

```
<body aurelia-app="main">
  <script src="scripts/vendor-bundle.js" data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper"></script>
</body>
```

I tryied to install it with `npm i raf performance-now` and configured in `aurelia_project/aurelia.json` but it's still not working.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score -1):

I'm using CLI and was able to target older versions of IE.

In main.ts, I simply added the following import:

```
import * as raf from 'raf';
```

And then in the configure() method, I added:

```
raf.polyfill();
```